# Query EF Core DbSet.Local slow

Tags: performance, entity-framework-core

I have been queering EF 6 DbSet.Local with great success for a number of years. However doing the same in EF Core is a factor 6 slower which unfortunately is a showstopper for me as I'm dealing with a huge amount of data which again prevent me to make the shift from EF 6 to EF Core.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Below please find an example which can be run both in EF 6. and EF Core

---

```
    private BlogContext _blogContext;

    public void BlogTest()
    {
        _logger.Information("BlogTest started");

        _blogContext = new BlogContext();
        _blogContext.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; // EF Core
        //_blogContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; // EF 6

        // Add blogs to context
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            _blogContext.Blogs.Add(new Blog { ID = i });
        }

        _logger.Information("BlogTest continued");

        // Loop blogs in context
        for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            foreach (var blog in _blogContext.Blogs.Local)
            {
            }
        }

        _logger.Information("BlogTest ended");
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    public class BlogContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blog;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved in upcoming EF Core 3.0

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14231

Answer (score 0):

This may be help [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7978)

check `BlogContext` model, EF Core not supported many thing yet.

Comment: Please don't post links as answer. If the link breaks the answer is useless. Always add a brief summary.